# Subversion broken with Xcode 4.0.1

Tags: xcode, svn, 64-bit

I have run into a rather annoying problem after updating to Xcode 4.0.1. Whenever I try to use subversion, either from within Xcode or from the command line, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _apr_stat$INODE64
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libsvn_subr-1.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.dylib

Trace/BPT trap
```

I suspect it has something to do with `libapr-1.0.dylib` missing 64 bit support, but I haven't got a clue how to fix it.

Anybody else ran into the same problem, or know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried the following:

```
shigerello> nm -arch all /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.3.8.dylib | grep architecture
/usr/lib/libapr-1.0.3.8.dylib (for architecture x86_64):
/usr/lib/libapr-1.0.3.8.dylib (for architecture i386):
/usr/lib/libapr-1.0.3.8.dylib (for architecture ppc7400):

shigerello> nm -arch all /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.3.8.dylib | grep apr_stat
00000000000085fc T _apr_stat
0000000000008956 T _apr_stat$INODE64
00007c9c T _apr_stat
00007fb4 T _apr_stat$INODE64
00007c1c T _apr_stat
00008014 T _apr_stat$INODE64
```

This is not much help, but it seems 64-bit is supported and the requested symbol (_apr_stat$INODE64) does exist in libapr-1.0.dylib. Hmm, odd.

Comment: Just tried the same for my libapr instance at it only had one entry named "_apr_stat". No "_apr_stat$INODE64"". Somehow my version have some different architectures than yours - the question is then how to fix it.

Comment: You're using Mac OSX 10.6, right? Xcode 4 is for 10.6.6+. Try Software Update to see if it updates libapr.

Comment: A cause I can think of is some community-contributed software package of some sort replaced libapr with its own "less compatible" version of libapr. You can revert to the PPC-i386-x86_64 version by copying libapr-*.dylib from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib to /usr/lib. Maybe you need to copy libaprutil-*.dylib also. If this wont work, copying all *dylib of the 10.6 SDK to your /usr/lib will work (this is almost the same as reinstalling OS just for /usr/lib).

Comment: I tried replacing the libapr and libaprutil dylibs with the versions from 10.s SDK. These versions does indeed have the fat binary. The problem is however that i'm getting a "can't map" error now.

Comment: It looks like more precise reversion is needed here. Now, take out Mac OS X 10.6 install DVD, and in Finder, cmd-shift-g to go to /Volumes/Mac OS X Install DVD/System/Installation/Packages/ (this is required due to System directory is hidden). Then open BSD.pkg & BaseSystem.pkg, and follow the installation instructions. It will revert all the system BSD & library environment back to factory settings. System reinstallation is the most reliable solution, but resource migration from previous OS is pain, so I hope this to work.

Comment: I'm somewhat reluctant to try to patch my running 10.6.7 with basic components from my 10.6.0 install DVD. I fear that this would really screw up my entire system and not just the svn installation.

Comment: For integration of the system, after reinstallation of the previous version components of Mac OS X, you should visit [link](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#macosx106) to download an appropriate update combo (e.g. Mac OS X v10.6.7 Update Combo), restart the PC, and perform Software Update to catch up the latest version of Mac OS X 10.6.